# How to empty Grub Customizer Trash?

Tags: grub2, bootloader, trash

I have customized Grub using Grub Customizer (version: 3.0.2). I have deleted some entries which are now in Grub Customizer Trash. Since I have no problem with Grub boot loader, so I want to empty Grub Customizer Trash. I have removed Grub Customizer using Synaptic Package Manager with "Mark for Complete Removal" and then installed again. Still no change. 27 items remain in Grub Customizer Trash.

Can I remove them?

Answer (score 0):

It is theoretically possible to empty GC Trash but you would be wasting your time.

The clever thing about Grub is that it is able to set itself up, by reading the available data on the disks. It does not require any configuration input as such.

Therefore if you were to empty the Trash, it would immediately reappear back on the main grub boot menu. The fact that these entries are in Trash, means that they will NOT reappear!

Having said all that, I am no expert, so it may be possible to permanently remove various options from the initial setup file - but this is a risky business and unnecessary.

Also any new Ubuntu version would re-instate all the previous options again.